# SwiftUI "Generic parameter 'Data' could not be inferred" when referencing variables from within ForEach

Tags: swiftui

So for some reason when I try to reference a variable within my ForEach it give me the following error: Generic parameter 'Data' could not be inferred, Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue"

I've really got no clue why this is throwing an error, it seems pretty straightforward to me but im stuck

```
    struct OptionsScrollView: View {

    @State var scrollOptions = [
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ]
    @State var optionHeight = 50

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{outerGeo in

        ScrollView{

            VStack{
                ForEach(self.scrollOptions.indices) {i in

                    GeometryReader {optionGeo in

                        Text( self.scrollOptions[i] )

                    } // end optionGeo
                        .frame(width: 100, height: self.optionHeight)
                        //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        //                         adding this gives me the error

                } // end ForEach

            } // end VStack

        } // end ScrollView

    } // end outerGeo
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the GeometryReader above my ScrollView fixed my issue, not sure why!

Answer (score 0):

correct this:   @State var optionHeight : CGFloat = 50

-> compiler assumes optionHeight is an Int, if you dont tell him ;)